# Problem with NodeJS and socket.io on iPad since April 7, 2020 update

Tags: node.js, ipad, socket.io

I have a website running with a small number of users since 2017. It uses socket.io and Node. Starting on April 7th, socket connections via iPad are failing. I'm not certain whether everyone with an iPad cannot connect, but I've worked with a handful of users on the issue and can't get them to connect reliably. I don't see anything in the iPadOS update release notes that suggests websocket changes or anything. The connection fails on all browsers.

Has anyone else seen this or have an idea how to solve it? I am using socket.io version 1.7.4.

Comment: What is on the client-side that you are using? Is it a JS based native application or you are using something else? Also, when you mentioned it fails on all browsers, what you mean by that?

Comment: I'm using standard JS on the client side. After I posted the question, I realized my version of NodeJS was out of date. I corrected that, and iPad users still can't connect.

By "it fails on all browsers", I just mean it doesn't seem to matter which browser iPad users try to use the site with. It doesn't work for iPad users, and every other kind of user seems to be working fine.